# IdentityServer4 Custom Token Request Validator Not Called

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 in my project with ASP.NET Identity. My goal is to add logic that will assign dynamic token expiration. I am following this topic from the IdSrv4 documentation about [ICustomTokenRequestValidator](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/custom_token_request_validation.html).

My initial validator is very basic.

```
public class TokenLifetimeValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is the IdSrv4 configuration:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(new IdentityResource[] { new IdentityResources.OpenId(), new IdentityResources.Profile() })
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(new ApiResource[] { new ApiResource("api", new[] { JwtClaimTypes.Name, JwtClaimTypes.Role }) })
    .AddInMemoryClients(new Client[]
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "api"
            },
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            RequireConsent = false,
            RedirectUris = Configuration.GetSection("RedirectUris").Get<string[]>(),
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = Configuration.GetSection("PostLogoutRedirectUris").Get<string[]>(),
            AccessTokenLifetime = 60*60*24, // 24 Hours
            IdentityTokenLifetime = 60*60*24 // 24 Hours
        }
    })
    // Not working.
    ---> //.AddCustomTokenRequestValidator<TokenLifetimeValidator>()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

// Not working.
---> services.AddTransient<ICustomTokenRequestValidator, TokenLifetimeValidator>();
```

Regardles of how I register the custom validator, it never gets executed. I tested with IdentityServer4 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.3.2, 2.4.0.

How can I get the validator to get executed?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
The login is executed by `oidc-client.js` and its `userManager.signinRedirect`.

```
this.userManager = new UserManager({
  authority: environment.issuer,
  client_id: 'client',
  scope: 'openid profile api',
  response_type: 'id_token token',
  loadUserInfo: true,
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  redirect_uri: environment.app + '/login-callback.html',
  silent_redirect_uri: environment.app + '/silent-renew.html',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: environment.app
});
```

Comment: How are you trying to invoke that? Via `connect/authorize` or `connect/token`?

Comment: I am using the oidc-client.js library for this and its `userManager.signinRedirect`. I believe it is calling `connect/authorize`.

Comment: So thats why your validator is not called, there is no token context to validate during the `connect/authorize` flow

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve setting a token expiration at runtime?

Comment: for `connect/authorize` use `ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator`

Comment: and you can add it directly after `.AddIdentityServer()`  -- just a helper, but makes your configuration more consistent

Answer (score 6):

It turned out that the appropriate interface to implement for my flow was `ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator`.

- connect/authorize - `ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator`
- connect/token - `ICustomTokenRequestValidator`

Thanks to *Vidmantas Blazevicius* and *d_f* for the pointers.